# Validar datos en excel sin macros

Tags: excel

En una pestaña tengo las columnas clave 1 y clave 2 que son las listas para poder elegir valores en la siguiente pestaña, en columna1 validaba por medio de data validation list que solo se pudieran ingresar datos de la columna clave1  de la primer pestaña y lo mismo con columna2 solo datos contenidos en clave2, pero ahora necesito validar que exista la combinacion entre la clave1 y clave2.

Por ejemplo si puse la clave 067 en columna1, solo pueda poner en columna2 las claves 178 y 890, por que existe esa combinacion en la primer pestaña.

No se si exista una manera de lograr la validacion al momento de escribir el valor  en columna 2 y si no existe la combinacion arrojar un error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]

Comment: Sin macros no es posible que yo sepa. Ten en cuenta que quieres filtrar un rango en base a otro y mostrarlo en una lista. Si bien las funciones de Excel 365 permite filtrar y ordenar, que yo sepa no pueden usarse en validación de datos.

Comment: @Esei Si me olvido del filtro y solo quiero validar los valores, se podra con puras formulas?

Comment: Mostrar en un desplegable los valores de clave2 asociados a un valor específico de clave1 no se puede mediante fórmulas, que yo sepa. No se me ocurre ninguna manera mediante lista desplegable. No sé si otro usuario sabrá la respuesta pero yo, desde luego, no se me ocurre ninguna.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que vamos a hacer es crear la lista de los valores que quieres que aparezcan usando formulas matriciales.

Primero creamos los "rangos con nombre" **clave1** y **clave2** y las columna1 y columna2 las voy a poner a continuación, en las columnas C y D para facilitar las fórmulas.

En la validación de daos la fórmula sería algo así:

```
=(clave1=C2) * clave2
```

Con esto obtienes la lista de los datos que quieres más un montón de ceros que no quieres y los puedes cambiar por una cadena vacía encerrándolo en un `SI`

```
=SI(  (clave1=C2) * clave2 =0 ; "" ; (clave1=C2) * clave2)
```

Las cadenas vacías se eliminan al crear la validación de datos.

***Puedes querer más***

El caso anterior se basa en que en **columna1** tienes el resultado de **clave1** y quieres validar el valor de **clave2**

Siguiendo los pasos anteriores puedes ampliar la fórmula a las dos opciones a elegir en **columna1**

```
SI( C2=A2 ; SI( (clave1=C2) * clave2 =0 ; "" ; (clave1=C2) * clave2) ; SI( (clave2=C2) * clave1 =0 ; "" ; (clave2=C2) * clave1) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Con fórmulas lo podrías hacer apoyándote en columnas auxiliares. Sería una especie de comprobación dinámica.

El primer paso es crear una tercera columna en la pestaña de las fórmulas. Concatenas el valor de clave1 y clave2, será una clave "maestra" unión de ambas:

```
=A2&B2
```

Ahora en la otra pestaña creas otra columna cuya misión es comprobar si existe en la pestaña anterior una combinación del valor de columna1 y columna2. Te comento dos formas:

-La más simple es con un contar.si() de tal forma que si su valor es uno o más es una combinación de claves válidas y si es cero no es valida:

```
=CONTAR.SI(Hoja1!C:C;Hoja2!A2&Hoja2!B2)
```

Nota: hoja1 la pestaña dónde están las claves

Señalar que si arrastras la fórmula donde no hay valores saldrá un valor muy alto igual al número de filas en blanco de la hoja.

Una ventaja del contar.si() es el hecho de permitirte verificar si tienes alguna dupla de clave1 y clave2 duplicada.

-Otra solución más elegante es añadir un par de si() anidados. Utilizaremos un si() para contemplar el caso de celdas donde no hay valores y otro si() para mostrar un mensaje confirmando la corrección de las claves o avisando que son incorrectas:

```
=SI(A2&B2="";"";SI(CONTAR.SI(Hoja1!C:C;Hoja2!A2&Hoja2!B2)>0;"Claves OK";"Claves incorrectas"))
```

Si no tenemos problemas en trabajar con una celda más o que esté oculta, la concatenación de A2&B2 en la segunda hoja puede ser hecha en otra columna y desde la columna con los si() y el contar.si() apuntar a esta nueva columna auxiliar. Ganaremos en legibilidad y tener una mejor base para explotar la hoja1.